# Keeping the trackpad disabled

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with classic GNOME window manager on a Lenovo Thinkpad x230.

I prefer to use the trackpoint over the trackpad. I disabled the trackpad in Applications > System Tools > Preferences > Mouse & Touchpad (setting the Touchpad on/off slider to "off")

Sometimes, after a reboot or when waking from hibernation, the trackpad turns back on, with the aforementioned slider in the "on" position.

How can I keep the trackpad/touchpad disabled through sleep/wake & system shutdown? I'd like to be able to turn it back on easily if I need it. I also want to keep using the Trackpoint buttons that are above the trackpad.